# Is it possible to allow multiple instances of a same air application to run at the same time?

Tags: multithreading, flash, air

Actually what I need is multithreading, but it seems I cannot have multithreading with just one instance of the application. But it seems adobe won't allow "multiprocessing", either?

Is there a way to walk around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Accidentally found a walk around:

... the application id is stored in plain text without packaging or any other ways preventing one from changing it. So I can just have several copies of the program with different id.